# Change default documentation location in visual studio express

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I would like that the generated documentation xml (and only that file) is copied to another location instead the /bin/debug folder, or copied right after the file is created.
Is this possible with Visual Studio Express 2013?

Answer (score 0):

If found no spot to change the Path, but you could use the Post-build events.

Go to your Project settings -> Compile -> Build Events... (lower right corner)

```
move "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).xml" "C:\DocXML\$(TargetName).xml"
```

When you enter this command in Post-build event command line it will copy the XML to `"C:\DocXML\"`

Otherwise you could use `move "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).xml" "C:\DocXML\*.xml"` to copy all `.xml`from your Build Dir.

`$(Text)`  are Macros which you can use with variable values.

[image: List of all Macros]

Comment: I don't see any "Build events" under Compile. I did a quick search, and this is only available in full versions non the Express editions :(

Comment: Ah okay sorry, don't know that about Express Edition.